# error in the selecting action and strange verification form

Tags: php, yii

Each application has instance. When I try propirat way to url mananager

```
'application/<slug:[\w+]+>/instance/create/' => 'instance/create',
'application/<slug:[\w+]+>/instance/<uuid:[\w0-9]+>/update/' => 'instance/update',
```

To open a link, set the path in the form of

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Create Instance', 'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('instance/create',  array('slug' => $model->application->slug, 'uuid' => $model->uuid))),
array('label'=>'Update Instance', 'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('instance/update', array('slug' => $model->application->slug, 'uuid' => $model->uuid))),
```

I get an error

```
include(optional_note.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What the file and that there has to be done to satisfy the referrals?

**Update**

```
public function actionCreate()                                         
{                                                                      
$model=new Instance;                                                  
    $model->application_id = $this->_application->id;                  

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed          
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);                              

if(isset($_POST['Instance']))                                         
{                                                                     
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Instance'];                               
    if($model->save())                                                   
            $this->redirect(array('view','uuid'=>$model->uuid));                
}                                                                     

$this->render('create',array(                                         
    'model'=>$model,                                                     
));                                                                   
}
```

**Update**

Now comes the strange behavior, gets the following field parameters

```
Stack Trace
#3 \yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\base\CModel.php(285): CValidator::createValidator("optional_note", Instance, "uuid", array(0 => "length", "max" => 128)) 
#4 \yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\base\CModel.php(259): CModel->createValidators()
#5 \yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\base\CModel.php(302): CModel->getValidators("uuid")
#6 \yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php(1197):  CModel->isAttributeRequired("uuid")
#7 \yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\web\widgets\CActiveForm.php(563): CHtml::activeLabelEx(Instance, "uuid", array()) 
#8 \protected\views\instance\_form.php(25): CActiveForm->labelEx(Instance, "uuid")


 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
 <div class="row">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'uuid'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,'uuid',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model,'uuid'); ?>
 </div>
  <div class="row">
```

Comment: please show your actionCreate in InstanceController

Comment: By Stack Track shows that breaks the application when calling the form, can not field validated uuid, but it is filled in automatically javascript

Comment: do you have another model `optional_note` that's part of the form for the `Instance` model? It looks like it's trying to load that and not finding the model class.

Comment: the exact line and line number where this error occurs is needed to solve this.

Comment: option_note is the next form field after uuid.It from the model Instance

Comment: @martinixs Do you wrote deamon on php? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

```
CValidator::createValidator("optional_note", Instance, "uuid", array(0 => "length", "max" => 128)),
```

Check rules for model

```
array('uuid', 'optional_note' ...
```

It's wrong, need put column names in same string

```
array('uuid, optional_note', ...
```

Comment: public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('uuid', 'required'),... 

there is not even necessary in this setting it there and do not need

Comment: @martinixs, check whole rules for 'optional_note': Find string in all files in your protected : `optional_note`

Comment: For your advice to check the following line length check and found the error.
array('uuid', 'option_node', 'length', 'max'=>128) here it is. Thanks!